# How can I send multi-values under 1 variable in URL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, url

How to send multi-values under 1 variable in URL? this variable can have comma, single quote etc...

I have a messy made-up values inside a DropDownList(could be more). I want to pass these 3 values in URL under 1 variable. I am using ASCII to encode &',/ symbols in url

- New York City / Buffalo
- Doctor's, Nurse's, hospital
- Red & Green

How can i indicate in URL that new value is about to start? i can't use comma becuase single value can have multi commas. and I cant use & symbol bc url think its a new variable

I tried this but ^ symbol not allowed in url

```
 test.com/Value=New York City / Buffalo^Doctor's, Nurse's, hospital^Red & Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to both form and destination pages, build a custom encoder to replace any invalid character in url (or query string) with something else and also a custom decoder at the destination page:

```
function encode(s as string) as string
    s= s.replace("&" , "@@@ampersand@@@")
    s= s.replace("^" , "@@@caret@@@")
    s= s.replace("/" , "@@@slash@@@")
    s= s.replace("|" , "@@@bar@@@")
    return s
end function

function decode(s as string) as string
    s= s.replace("@@@ampersand@@@" , "&")
    s= s.replace("@@@caret@@@" , "^")
    s= s.replace("@@@slash@@@" , "/")
    s= s.replace("@@@bar@@@" , "|")
    return s
end function
```

In your form page:

```
dim s as string= $"{string1}|{string2}|{string3}"
response.redirect("testcom/somepage.aspx/?value=" & encode(s))
```

In somepage.aspx :

```
dim k as string= decode(request.querystring("value"))
dim a = k.split("|")
string1= a(0)
string2= a(1)
string3= a(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shove the 3 (or however many) into an array.
Use encoding, and then convert to JSON array.

So, say this markup:

```
    <h3>Source page</h3>
    one:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    two:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    one:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThree" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />

    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="cmdJS" type="button" value="client  side click"
        onclick="mytest();return false" />

    </div>

    <script>
        function mytest() {
            var mythings = []
            mythings.push($('#txtOne').val())
            mythings.push($('#txtTwo').val())
            mythings.push($('#txtThree').val())

            var sParms = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(mythings))
            window.location.href = "MyTest.aspx?myvalues=" + sParms

        }
    </script>
```

And our target page has this:

```
    <h3>Target page</h3>
    one:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    two:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    one:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThree" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
```

So, say then this:

[image]

Code behind on target page is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim s = Request.QueryString(0)
        Dim jsSZ = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim mylist As New List(Of String)
        Dim myarray = jsSZ.Deserialize(Of List(Of String))(s)

        txtOne.Text = myarray(0)
        txtTwo.Text = myarray(1)
        txtThree.Text = myarray(2)

    End If

End Sub
```